# Customize Oauth2+JWT token response with spring boot

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Oauth2+JWT+Spring security in one of my project. When i hit /outh/token using username/password i am receiving access token in the response with other details like

```
{
    "access_token": <token>,
    "token_type": <type>,
    "refresh_token": <refresh-token>,
    "expires_in":<secs>,
    "scope": <scope>,
    "jti": <value>
}
```

Is it possible to customize this response like

```
{
    data: {
         "access_token": <token>,
         "token_type": <type>,
         "refresh_token": <refresh-token>,
         "expires_in":<secs>,
         "scope": <scope>,
         "jti": <value>
       },
  details:{
//extra information 
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add data about identified user or about the token issuance?

Comment: @ch4mp I need to add custom data under details and acces_token details under data

Comment: You don't answer my question: **what** is this data (not where do tou want to put it)?

Comment: It basically the format we send it to client for every response, where we send the actual data under "data" tag and any extra meta data under "details" tag, that's how the client parses the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused, don't know how to ask more clearly: "what is the additional data you want to send?". Just give an explicit sample.

I'll answer guessing that this data is related to the authorized entity (the user when answering within authorization-code flow and the client within client-credentials flow): **non standard data should be set as private-claims**, inside the JWT itself and on token introspection endpoint.

How to add such private claims depends on your authorization-server. For spring-security one, this is done with an [`OAuth2TokenCustomizer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-customizer). For Keycloak, you have to provide a "mapper", etc.

The client which received a payload like the one you show, will only send the access-token when issuing requests to resource-server(s). It is important that this token holds all of the data needed for resources access decisions. Some claims are specified by OAuth2, OpenID defines some more standard claims, and you are free to put whatever additional data in private claims (within the limits of the maximum token size).

Also, if your client needs to read claims, it should use ID token, not access-token (request `openid` scope when initiating OAuth2 flow). Access-token should be interpreted by resource-server only.